# Java hibernate Restriction.ne not include entities with null

Tags: java, hibernate

I try get a list by criteria using `Restrictions.ne("status","ERROR")` but method returns the list without entities where `status is null`.

```
public List<Match_soccer> getDayMatches(Date day){
    //Match_soccer where date between start and end dates and status != null
    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Match_soccer.class);
    criteria.add(Restrictions.between("start", day, DateJobs.addnHours(DateJobs.nextDay(day), 3)));
    criteria.add(Restrictions.ne("status","ERROR"));
    return criteria.list();
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Include an explicit null check:

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.or(
   Restrictions.ne("status","ERROR"),
   Restrictions.isNull("status"))
);
```

The point is that most databases evaluate comparison operators with `null` arguments to `false`, meaning that both `status = null` and `status <> null` are considered `false`.

Answer (score 1):

The criteria is well written, it should work .

Have you tried to remove the date filter to see if that is filtering "status=null" ?

Comment: I try remove `criteria.add(Restrictions.ne("status","ERROR"));` then return with null